# Google Play referral code from one app to another

Tags: android, google-play

I'm looking to link to another app from my own, and have the other app be able to track referrals. I'm not the developer on the linked-to app, so I can only assume they set up their BroadcastReceiver to do this correctly.

However on my end, the flow for a user being linked to another app using an http URL is very poor, with little or no conversion being the likely outcome. I'd sooner just directly link the users to the Google Play app. However, I don't know (and can't find any documentation one way or another) online saying whether or not referrals work the same or at all when using the market:// uri to link the user to the Google Play store.

Normally, you would generate an url like this:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example&referrer=utm_source%3Dfrommyapp%26utm_medium%3Dandroid%26utm_term%3Dbutton`

(from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#referrals)

I'd like to do something more like this:

`market://details?id=com.example&referrer=utm_source%3Dfrommyapp%26utm_medium%3Dandroid%26utm_term%3Dbutton`

Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: This seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018512/android-google-play-intent-referrer